# recover invisible folders caused by mac osx disk eject

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, macbook, usb-storage

I have 2TB Adata USB 3.0 hdd.
I connected it to mac book pro and due to wire issue the hdd got disconnected. After the incident the hdd's ntfs partition shows space full but not showing all folders. How do I fix it ? Some recovery software's shows all data and I can also recover the data. is it possible to fix the partition without recovering 2tb data to another disk ?

Answer (score -1):

Try [Disk Drill](http://download.cnet.com/Disk-Drill/3000-2094_4-76277044.html), this software can help you to find lost partition.

Here is an overview from their CNET page:

> Disk Drill is ready to become your trusted hard drive recovery software in any scenario: accidental data deletion, emptied Recycle Bin, virus attack, **lost or inaccessible partition**, power failure, boot record corruption, etc.

Disk Drill helps with:
**Partition loss**;
Hard drive reformatting;
Failed bootups;
Accidental deletion;
Recycle bin cleanup;
Memory card corruption.

Disk Drill recovers lost or deleted FAT or NTFS partitions. I use Disk Drill for Windows almost 2 months. It is freeware.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please see the site recommendations for [what do to when recommending software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). In short, you need to give more detail and explain how the software you're suggesting answers the question.